# Geo Chart how to add label text?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I need to add label text to the google geo chart, however I can't find any useful api reference which would show all of the options of the "legend".

I tried with zero effect(shows the colour palette line and range values , but no text"

```
legend: {text: 'hello', title: 'hello', numberFormat: '###', textStyle: {color: 'gray', fontSize: 16}
```

All of the sources seem to be focused on disabling the legend rather than enhancing it.

Comment: Amazingly interesting silence, when we generate charts for clients we have button which allows to download them as images, adding titles and legends to original html chart won't help as it won't appear inside the png. If you know how to include html titles into final generated image pls tell.

Comment: The legend option only has `numberFormat` and `textStyle` suboptions, there is no support for adding additional text to the legend, but you can file a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/list) to add support.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but if you change your HTML overlays to SVG nodes and add them to the chart's SVG, they should appear in the image after conversion to png.